# how to remove parcelRequire is not defined with peerjs in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, peerjs

i am building a video chat application with ionic 5, i dont know how to properly use it, i tried but i keep getting this error in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: parcelRequire is not defined
    at push../node_modules/peerjs/dist/peerjs.min.js.parcelRequire.EgBh (peerjs.min.js:1)
    at Object../node_modules/peerjs/dist/peerjs.min.js
```

Here is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Peer from 'peerjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root' 
}) 
export class WebrtcService {
    peer: Peer;
    myStream: MediaStream;
    myEl: HTMLMediaElement;
    partnerEl: HTMLMediaElement;
    options:any= {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9000,
        path: '/peerjs',
        debug: 3,
        config: {
            'iceServers': [{
                    url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'
                },{
                    url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                    credential: 'muazkh',
                    username: 'webrtc@live.com'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    constructor() {}

    getMedia() {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true },stream=>this.handleSuccess(stream),
        (error) =>this.handleError(error));
    }

    async init(userId: string, myEl: HTMLMediaElement, partnerEl: HTMLMediaElement) {
        this.myEl = myEl;
        this.partnerEl = partnerEl;
        try {
            this.getMedia();
        } catch (e) {
            this.handleError(e);
        }
        await this.createPeer(userId);
    }

    async createPeer(userId: string) {
        this.peer = new Peer(userId, this.options);
        this.peer.on('open', ()=>this.wait())
    }

    call(partnerId: string) {
        const call = this.peer.call(partnerId, this.myStream);
        call.on('stream', (stream)=>this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream);
    }

    wait() {
        this.peer.on('call', (call) => {
            call.answer(this.myStream);
            call.on('stream', (stream) =>this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream);
        });
    }
```

icomment most of the code to find out where the error is coming from, i noticed that the error happens when `this.peer = new Peer(userId, this.options);` is being runned.

Also i noticed that if i should run this in other pages it will work, but if it is being run in a app.component.ts, it will give me that error, i seriously need the above code to be in app.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var parcelRequire;
</script>
```

(From [here](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/753).)

Comment: Solved the issue for Stencil.js integration for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your script uses `type="module"` - remove it.

Comment: hi can you elaborate for the knowledge purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

It is solved in parcel version 2,
simply install parcel

```
npm i -D parcel
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For some reason, this isn't in the "Getting Started" section of the Parcel documentation.  I bootstrapped an app from scratch, installing only minimal dependencies for react.  Then installed only `parcel-bundler` and got this error.  Installed `parcel` as well, and it's fixed.